# Splitting to 2D array

Tags: javascript

How I can split a string into 2D array. String is like

```
1c2c3r4c5c6r6c8c9
```

array should be like

```
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var src = "1c2c3r4c5c6r6c8c9";
var rows = src.split(/r/);

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    rows[i] = rows[i].split(/c/);
```

Please note that I didn't test this so it might contain a syntax error or something...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the map method on `Array`

```
var s = "1c2c3r4c5c6r6c8c9";
var rows = s.split("r");
result = rows.map(function (x) {
    return x.split('c');
}));
```

`map` is introduced in ECMAScript5 and is not supported in older browsers. But, there is a decent work-around [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "1c2c3r4c5c6r6c8c9";
var result = [];
var group = str.split("r");
for(i in group) {result.push(group[i].split("c"))};
```

result should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var src = "1c2c3r4c5c6r6c8c9";
var rows = src.split(/r/g);

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].split(/c/g);
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        cells[j] = parseInt(cells[j]);
    }
    rows[i] = cells;
}
```